# Compiling Openresty into a .deb package

Tags: nginx, debian-wheezy

I'm trying to compile Openresty 1.7.2.1 into a .deb package for Debian 7 using FPM. Although the FPM compilation is successful and I get a deb file, but when I install it using dpkg somehow the config files are not getting placed in /etc/nginx and obviously when I run /usr/sbin/nginx I get:

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Following are the steps I'm taking for compilation:

```
./configure --with-luajit \
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body \
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy \
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock \
--pid-path=/run/nginx.pid \
--with-pcre-jit \
--with-pcre \
--with-http_ssl_module \
--without-http_redis2_module \
--without-http_redis_module \
--without-http_memc_module \
--without-http_memcached_module
```

Then

```
make
INSTALL=/tmp/openresty
make install DESTDIR=$INSTALL
mkdir -p $INSTALL/var/lib/nginx
```

And finally

```
fpm -s dir -t deb -n openresty -v 1.7.2.1 --iteration 1 -C $INSTALL \
--description "Openresty 1.7.2.1" \
-d libpcre3 \
--config-files /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf.default \
--config-files /etc/nginx/win-utf \
--config-files /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params \
--config-files /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
--config-files /etc/nginx/koi-win \
--config-files /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.default \
--config-files /etc/nginx/mime.types.default  \
--config-files /etc/nginx/koi-utf \
--config-files /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params.default  \
--config-files /etc/nginx/mime.types \
--config-files /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf \
etc usr var run
```

After FPM runs I get

```
Created package {:path=>"openresty_1.7.2.1-1_amd64.deb"}
```

When I install using dpkg I get only the following files in /etc/nginx

```
scgi_params  scgi_params.default  uwsgi_params  uwsgi_params.default
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add any `--config-files` options to fpm. Just having the config files located in `/tmp/openresty/etc/nginx` is sufficient. I suspect that pointing those options at non-existing files is what is causing your problems.

If you want the Debian standard Nginx config with sites-available and sites-enabled then you need to add the relevant files to your package tree in `/tmp/openresty/etc/nginx` before building the package.

For reference I just open sourced my own OpenResty package builder here: https://github.com/tapstream/openresty-debian.